# How to match array data from Input Text Data and Input File Data when one input file is empty?

Tags: php, jquery

Table Screenshot
[image: 1]

As you can see in the screenshot above that I have table and the 2nd row input file is empty.

Also, I have an update button to get all input texts and input files for ajax call.

```
 $('body').on('click', '#btn-update',function() { 


        var data = new FormData($('#frm-edit-bulk-category')[0]);

        var file_data = $('input[type="file"]');

        for (var i = 0; i < file_data.length; i++) 
            data.append("icon[]", file_data[i].files[0]);            
        

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "post",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                //success
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //error
            }
        });
    
    });
```

Result from PHP Back-End

```
 Array
    (
        [max_tabs] => 10
        [post] => Array
            (
                [description] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Desc1
                        [1] => Desc2
                        [2] => Desc3
                    )
    
                [category_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Impulse
                        [1] => Pneumatic
                        [2] => Fencing Staplers
                    )
    
                [uniq_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1602210787401
                        [1] => 1602210787416
                        [2] => 1602210787425
                    )
    
                [parent_category] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [2] => 3
                    )
    
                [display_order] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 2
                        [2] => 3
                    )
    
                [prev_file_name] => no-image-icon.png
                [icon] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => undefined
                    )
    
            )
    
        [files] => Array
            (
                [icon] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => mkA5h783.jpeg
                                [1] => —Pngtree—wooden board empty table with_1160858.png
                            )
    
                        [type] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => image/jpeg
                                [1] => image/png
                            )
    
                        [tmp_name] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD507.tmp
                                [1] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpD508.tmp
                            )
    
                        [error] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 0
                                [1] => 0
                            )
    
                        [size] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 261354
                                [1] => 1660148
                            )
    
                    )
    
            )
    
    )
```

I was just wondering how I will match the array data between **3 data from $_POST values** and **2 data from $_FILES values**.

I would just like to happen is to match the POST and FILES Data however, the 2nd input file is empty.

$_POST DATA

```
  [description] => Array
    (
                            [0] => Desc1
                            [1] => Desc2
                            [2] => Desc3
     )
```

$_FILES DATA

```
[name] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => mkA5h783.jpeg
                                [1] => —Pngtree—wooden board empty table with_1160858.png
                            )
```

Thanks!

Comment: you could devise a way to put an index in the name attribute, so that the indices line up when you submit. even when no file is submitted in between, you can just refer to the keys

Comment: Hi @Kevin , How I am going to index it? Thanks

Comment: just simply use an index on the file append `data.append("icon["+i+"]", file_data[i].files[0]);`

Comment: @kevin, Ohh I see. Got it now!! Thanks a lot!